# Update all rows associated to duplicates of another table

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.6

We have two tables: `cars` and `views`.

```
Cars            Views
---+-------     ---+-------
id | desc       id | car_id
---+-------     ---+-------
1  | desc1      1  | 1
2  | Desc1      2  | 2
3  | desc2      3  | 3
```

The problem is with the `desc` field in the table cars. That row had to be unique but we unfortunately allowed the users to fill in uppercased values, which brought us to the situation of having (according to the example above) two duplicated rows: `desc1` and `Desc1`.

The way to fix that is `DELETE` the duplicated cars, and keep only the first one. We know how to deal with that.

Our problem comes before that, when updating the related table, where some views are associated to a car which has a duplicated desc (for instance a car which is going to be removed). Those views should be updated for being assigned to the first of the duplicated cars (in this case the car id #1)

After the `UPDATE`, we'd like this result in views:

```
Views
---+-------
id | car_id
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 3
```

We are able to get all the ids of the duplicated cars and deal with the deletion but we're stuck with this `UPDATE`.

Comment: is the id of the duplicate always *higher* then the id of the real row? as in inserted after, in the case of an auto-incremental id column?

Comment: Exactly, the duplicated we want to remove are the ones with higher ids. We only want to keep the one with the lower id.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be to create a mapping table with before/after values for description `id`s.

The result should look something like:

```
Before | After
---------------
1      | 1
2      | 1
3      | 3
```

That table can be created with something like this:

```
SELECT
    cars.id AS before_id,
    fixed.lowest_id AS after_id
FROM cars
JOIN (
    -- The lowest id value for each duplicate description
    SELECT
        MIN(id) AS lowest_id,
        LOWER(desc) AS lower_desc
    FROM cars
    GROUP BY LOWER(desc)
) fixed
ON LOWER(cars.desc) = fixed.lower_desc
```

You can then have your views match to that mapping table to pull the new "correct" `id` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Views AS v
JOIN (SELECT c1.id AS oldID, MIN(c2.id) AS newID
      FROM Cars AS c1
      JOIN Cars AS c2 ON LOWER(c1.desc) = LOWER(c2.desc)
      HAVING oldID != newID) AS c
    ON v.car_id = oldID
SET v.car_id = newID
```

The subquery finds the primary ID for each ID that contains a duplicate description. Joining this with the `Views` table provides the information needed to make the replacements.

Comment: Shouldn't we set any `GROUP BY` inside subquery to get result grouped and filtered correctly? `GROUP BY LOWER(c1.desc)` for example?

Comment: No grouping is needed, we just need to pair each duplicate with its primary, which the `ON` clause does. If there's more than 1 duplicate, grouping will miss the extras.